# Why does sha1_hex("test") return a different value than Digest::SHA->sha1_hex("test")?

Tags: perl

I'm curious why this gives the right answer:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(sha1_hex);
print sha1_hex("test");
```

But this doesn't:

```
use Digest::SHA;
print Digest::SHA->sha1_hex("test");
```

Answer (score 6):

`sha1_hex` is not a method. You want

```
Digest::SHA::sha1_hex("test")
```

---

```
Digest::SHA->sha1_hex("test")
```

is basically equivalent to

```
Digest::SHA->can('sha1_hex')->("Digest::SHA", "test")
```

Notice the extra argument.

Answer (score 4):

The use of arrow notation in `Digest::SHA->sha1_hex("test")` causes the function call to be parsed as a method call on the package/class (same thing in Perl) `Digest::SHA`, which means that Perl will actually do `Digest::SHA::sha1_hex('Digest::SHA', 'test')`.  To do what you want, write `Digest::SHA::sha1_hex('test')` instead.